# Dynamic Enum Property - Maximum Recursions Exceeded

Tags: python, properties

Hello Blender/Python friends. I am having an issue I am hoping you can help me with.

I have a dynamic enum property that shows a dropdown with a list of current objects that fit certain criteria:

```
my_enum_dt_wall_items : bpy.props.EnumProperty(
    name = "dt_wall_items",
    description = "Wall Items",
    items = wall_items_func,
    default = None,
    update = wall_item_update_func
    )
```

I wrote this function to update the enum items:

```
def wall_items_func(self, context):

    items = []
    current_wall = bpy.data.scenes["Scene"].my_tool.my_enum_dt_wall_number

    for obj in bpy.data.objects[:]:
        
        if current_wall in obj.name_full:
            if len(obj.name_full) < 9:
                value = obj.name_full
                visible_name = obj.name_full.replace("dt_","").capitalize().replace("_"," ")
                final = (value, visible_name,"")
                items.append(final)
            elif "Window" in obj.name_full or "Door" in obj.name_full:
                if "boolean" not in obj.name_full:
                    value = obj.name_full
                    visible_name = obj.name_full[9:].replace("_"," ")
                    final = (value, visible_name,"")
                    items.append(final)
                
    
    item = ("NONE","None","")
    items.append(item)

    return items
```

When I import a new object (which changes the enum value to that item's name) I am getting the following error:

```
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
File "C:\Users\Tony\Documents\3D Printing\CharacterCreator\Base\UnlimitedTerrainCreator_v0-2.blend\Unlimited Terrain Creator", line 1128, in wall_items_func
WARN (bpy.rna): K:\BlenderGit\blender\source\blender\python\intern\bpy_rna.c:1457 pyrna_enum_to_py: current value '1' matches no enum in 'MySettings', '', 'my_enum_dt_wall_items'
```

It seems this function keeps recursively calling itself, and I'm not sure why. I do have an update function for this property as well, but that function isn't getting called (at least not multiple times).

Does anyone have an idea as to what could be causing this, or at least how to go about trouble-shooting it?

Thank you.

Comment: Hello, looks like the culprit is `wall_item_update_func`, is it trying to access the enum items ?

Comment: Same as last time, replace `bpy.data.scenes["Scene"]` by `context.scene`... I also would suggest replace `bpy.data.objects[:]`by `context.scene.objects[:]`: https://docs.blender.org/api/current/info_quickstart.html?highlight=context#context

Comment: @Gorgious That's what I thought too, but that function doesn't access the items. I tried getting rid of it just to see and still got the error

Comment: @brockmann  good suggestion, thanks. Unfortunately I'm still getting the same error